# Python - Can't get overload to work

Tags: python, overloading

All, I've been at this for a couple of days now and still cannot get this overload to work.

```
Error:
    setA: {-10,-8,3,5,10,17,20}
    intSet.len(setA):
    TypeError: __len__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Code:

```
class intSet(object):
    """An intSet is a set of integers
    The value is represented by a list of ints, self.vals.
    Each int in the set occurs in self.vals exactly once."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty set of integers"""
        self.vals = []

    def insert(self, e):
        """Assumes e is an integer and inserts e into self""" 
        if not e in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(e)

    >>>>>> more methods left out for brevity <<<<<<<<<<

    def __len__(self, s):
        """ Returns the length of the string provided"""
        return len(s)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I should also mention that it appears to work under canopy/Python 2.7 on my Macbook Pro but not on the MIT edX web based grader. I don't know what version the grader is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__len__` magic method does not take extra arguments. Your code should be

```
class IntSet(object):
"""An intSet is a set of integers
The value is represented by a list of ints, self.vals.
Each int in the set occurs in self.vals exactly once."""

def __init__(self):
    """Create an empty set of integers"""
    self.vals = []

>>>>>> more methods left out for brevity <<<<<<<<<<

def __len__(self):
    """Returns the number of elements in this set"""
    return len(self.vals)
```

Then in your code you use it this way

```
myset = IntSet()
print 'My set contains ', len(myset)
myset.insert(9)
myset.insert(10)
print 'My set contains ', len(myset)
myset.insert(9)
print 'My set contains ', len(myset)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class intSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = []

    def insert(self, e):
        if not e in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(e)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.vals)

s = intSet()

s.insert(1)
s.insert(2)
s.insert(3)
s.insert(2)

print(len(s))
# 3
```